# (The) school sucks

Tags: articles

Say, you're a student at a school; you feel the specific school you're enrolled in sucks; and you're talking to another student enrolled in the same school.

Can you simply say (a) 'School sucks' or do you have to say (b) 'Our school sucks' or (c) 'The school sucks'?

Is it ever possible that you can use (a) when referring to the specific school you're enrolled in?

Comment: *School sucks* means schooling sucks (everywhere). *The schools sucks* means a particular school sucks, and the context of the conversation will determine which one. *Our school sucks* leaves no doubt as to which one.

Comment: 'School' meaning 'our school' is certainly possible.